# Show Specific Value

Tags: php, ajax

This is the code i try but when i select an item it show some array ouput i just want the specific value that i selected. like white-house

```
  <select id="item">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="white-house">The White House</option>         
    </select>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function makeAjaxRequest(opts){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: { opts: opts },
          url: "tryonly.php",
          success: function(res) {
            $("#results").html("<p> " + res + "</p>");
          }
        });
      }

      $("#item").on("change", function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        makeAjaxRequest(selected);
      });
    </script>
```

In php code

```
<?php 

  echo '<pre>'; 
  print_r($_POST);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

the output when i select item

```
Array
(
    [opts] => white-house
)
```

Comment: That's what `print_r()` does...

Comment: how will output the specific value ?

Comment: `echo $_POST['opts']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
  echo $_POST['opts'];
```